# roboguice inject from inflated layout

Tags: android, layout-inflater, roboguice

I am using Roboguice (love it so far) on a RoboListFragment class.  For the header, I need to inflate the layout I want.  I'd be nice to then @InjectView from that inflated view, rather than the default content view.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is it exactly that you want to do?

Comment: I want to use the standard call to 
        getListView().addHeaderView();

I'm just wondering if there's a way I can inject it, rather than inflating it myself.